# Query to add into multiple tables not working

Tags: php, sql

I've got a query which should insert data into multiple tables, but I get a 500 error when I try to execute it.

What is the problem?

**My Query:**

```
$addcompany = "
    BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO company (name, street, zip, place, phone, contact, email, logo)
      VALUES('".$name."', '".$street."', '".$zip."', '".$place."', '".$phone."', '".$contact."', '".$email."', '".$file."');
  INSERT INTO users (username, password)
      VALUES('".$username."', '".$pass."');
  COMMIT";
  $addcompany = $conn->query($updatecompany);
```

I post using ajax, and the 500 error shows me this line:

```
 c = c("abort");
 try {
   h.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null)
 } catch (i) {
   if (c)
     throw i
   }
```

It's a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Is there any inner exception to the 500 error?

Comment: @TabAlleman I added more information in my original question

Comment: @jarlh SQL phpmyadmin and for my queries/connection mysqli